# Showing only the search results without displaying the whole table

Tags: php, html, sql

I want the webpage to show the results once the search button is clicked. Currently, the whole table is displayed while the page is loading.
If I change the value of the variable $sql from “Select * FROM users” then the search query doesn’t work anymore

I’m using XAMPP with webpage being a php file and the database is Mariadb

### users table

```
+--------+-------------+---------------+--------------------------+--------+
|    ID  |  firstname  |  lastname     |    address               |  count |
|        |             |               |                          |        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     1  |    john     |    doe        |james street, idaho, usa  |  2     |                    
|        |             |               |                          |        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     2  |    cindy    |   smith       |rollingwood av,lyn, canada| 1      |
|        |             |               |                          |        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     3  |    rita     |   chatsworth  |arajo ct, alameda, cali   | 0      |
|        |             |               |                          |        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     4  |    randy    |   plies       |smith spring, lima, (peru)| 1      |                       
|        |             |               |                          |        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     5  |    Matt     |   gwalio      |park lane, (atlanta), usa | 2      |
|        |             |               |                          |        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The webpage with search bar.

```php
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '1042M');
$localhost = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "samueldb";
$con = new mysqli($localhost, $username, $password, $dbname);
if( $con->connect_error){
  die('Error: ' . $con->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";

if( isset($_GET['btn']) ){
  $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, htmlspecialchars($_GET['search']));
   $sql =  "SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'firstname' ='$name'";
}
$result = $con->query($sql);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <title>Find my search results</title>
<link href="css/templatemo-style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="css/search-style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>

  <h2>List of students</h2>

     <div class="search">

    <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
    <button type="search" class="searchButton">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
   </button>
 </div>
</div>
           <table class="table table-striped table-dark">
           <tr>
           <th>ID</th>
           <th>First_Name</th>
           <th>Address</th>
           <th>Count</th>
           </tr>

           <?php

            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

               ?>
               <tr>
               <td><?php echo $row['ID']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['count']; ?></td>
               </tr>

               <?php
              }
               ?>
           </table>
           </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues going on to your code.

1. Your `form`. You forgot to wrap your inputs inside a [`form`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) tag. You should also add a `name="search"` on your input, and `type="search"` on `button` doesn't make sense. Change your form to

```html
<form>
    <input type="search" name="search" class="searchTerm" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
    <button type="submit" name="btn" class="searchButton">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </button>
</form>
```

*`name` attributes should match on your `$_GET[name]`*.

2. Your search query. You should put single quotes on the value only, not on columns. Change your query to

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname = '$name'";
```

3. **And most importantly**, you are not using prepared statements and parameterized queries.What your are doing is vulnerable from SQL injection attack. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) ASAP.

Comment: I plugged in your code and  the search results still showed up when I opened the page.

Comment: Maybe because you still have the `btn` parameter on the url. If it exists our search query will be used.

Comment: There are no button parameters on the url until the search button is clicked.

Comment: I noticed that I've the following line that may be causing the table to be displayed as the page is loaded:
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'users' "

But if I remove this line then I get an error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\opensourcetest.php:58 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\opensourcetest.php on line 58 `